# Allocate multidimensional array using new

Tags: c++, exception, initialization, try-catch, new-operator

When I allocate multidimensional arrays using `new`, I am doing it this way:

```
void manipulateArray(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols[])
{
  typedef Fred* FredPtr;
  FredPtr* matrix = new FredPtr[nrows];

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new Fred[ ncols[i] ];

}
```

where `ncols[]` contains the length for each element in `matrix`, and `nrows` the number of element in `matrix`.

If I want to populate `matrix`, I then have

```
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
      for (unsigned j = 0; j < ncols[i]; ++j) {
        someFunction( matrix[i][j] );
```

But I am reading [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/multidim-arrays.html), who is telling be to be very careful. I should initialize each row with `NULL` first. Then, I should `trycatch` the allocation for rows. I really do not understand why all this. I have always (but I am in the beginning) initialized in C style with the above code.

FAQ wants me to do this

```
void manipulateArray(unsigned nrows, unsigned ncols[])
{
  typedef Fred* FredPtr;

  FredPtr* matrix = new FredPtr[nrows];

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
    matrix[i] = NULL;

  try {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i)
      matrix[i] = new Fred[ ncols[i] ];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
      for (unsigned j = 0; j < ncols[i]; ++j) {
        someFunction( matrix[i][j] );
      }
    }

  }
  catch (...) {
    for (unsigned i = nrows; i > 0; --i)
      delete[] matrix[i-1];
    delete[] matrix;
    throw;    // Re-throw the current exception
  }

}
```

1/ Is it farfetched or very proper to always initialize so cautiously ?

2/ Are they proceeding this way because they are dealing with non built-in types? Would code be the same (with same level of cautiousness) with `double* matrix = new double[nrows];` ?

Thanks

EDIT

Part of the answer is in [next item in FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/multidim-arrays2.html)

Comment: Protip: things like `std::vector` know how to do this correctly.

Comment: @antitrust asks for the low-solution, so a high-level approach is not helpful. hint: a new can fail (out-of-memory)

Comment: Unless you need to reference individual rows/columns, a naive implementation with a 1D vector and suitable two index access is quite suitable for a dynamic matrix structure.

Comment: Just a minor comment: The deletion-loop in the catch-block should delete all allocated memory, including `matrix[0]`. Therefor, the loop should be modified to `for (unsigned i = nrows; i` **>=** `0; --i)`.

Comment: @JSQuareD I am doing `delete[] matrix[i-1];` with `i-1` right?

Comment: @antitrust Ah, you're completely right! **headdesk** I guess I just assumed you'd write your reverse loops like I would. Sorry!

Comment: @JSQuareD BTW, can you understand why FAQ uses `i-1` in loop and not `i` ? claimed reason is obscure : "This prevents wrap-around of the unsigned value when i goes one step below zero."

Comment: @antitrust When `i==0`, and you decrement it, it will wrap-arround to the highest possible value, because (since it's an unsigned variable) it cannot hold negative values. If that were to happen, the loop would not terminate and you would be trying to access memory that doesn't exist (something like `matrix[2000000000]`). In the loop you gave, `i` never becomes negative. Instead, the loop terminates when `i==0`.

Comment: thanks!  this    is     my      answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for being this careful is that you'll have memory leaks if any of those allocations fail, or if the Fred constructor throws. If you were to catch the exception higher up the callstack, you have no handles to the memory you allocated, which is a leak.

1) It's correct, but generally if you're going to this much trouble to protect against memory leaks, you'd prefer to use `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr` (and so on) to manage memory for you.

2) It's the same for built-in types, though at least then the only exception that will be thrown is `std::bad_alloc` if the allocation fails.

Comment: I think that initialization to `NULL` is needed in case this is not working `matrix[i] = new Fred[ ncols[i] ];`. Because in `for (unsigned i = nrows; i > 0; --i)
      delete[] matrix[i-1];` it is OK to delete a `NULL`, but not a non initialized thing. Is that correct ?

Comment: That's exactly right, yes - uninitialised pointers will have garbage values which are unsafe to delete, but it's completely safe to delete NULL. And you need to set them to NULL before you start doing things that might throw exceptions, because otherwise you don't know which ones point to things you've allocated and which ones are uninitialised.

Comment: Also, if you're using a new-ish compiler (which supports the new version of the standard, called C++11), the new way of saying null is `nullptr`. The old way of saying it (`NULL`) is discouraged in modern C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it depends on the target platform and the requirements to your system. If safety is a high priority and / or if you can run out of memory, then no, this is not farfetched. However, if you are not concerned too much with safety and you know that the users of your system will have ample free memory, then I would not do this either.

It does not depend on whether builtin-types are used or not. The FAQ solution is nulling the pointers to the rows so that in the event of an exception, only those rows which have already been created are deleted (and not some random memory location).

That said, I can only second R. Martinho Ferndandes' comment that you should use STL containers for this. Managing your own memory is tedious and dangerous.